# default value of parameter that is dependent on another parameter not updating in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Hi I have 2 parameters @begdate and @enddate.

When I select the @begdate ,I want @enddate to dynamically be set to the end of that current month.

I have @enddate default value as

```
=Format(DateSerial(Year(Parameters!BEGDATE.Value), Month(Parameters!BEGDATE.Value), "1").AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1),"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

It works the inital time of running the report, but when I change the @begdate to something else a second time the @enddate does not change with it.

Comment: have a look at this post https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3560/dynamically-refresh-sql-server-reporting-services-report-date-parameters/

Comment: You can try setting your parameter to always refresh in the advanced pane of your parameter property window.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this glitch before, for @enddate I over came it by setting the available  value to the same as the default value. Also in report parameter properties/ advanced, change refresh data when parameter changes to always refresh.

Comment: thank you. That looks like an excellent solution only problem is that,I can no longer change the date to via the calender method , It ONLY shows the calculated value.

Comment: looks like this is a known issue. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/268032/default-does-not-get-refreshed-for-cascading-parameters